# shell scripting:concatenate numeric and alphanumeric data types in shell and assign to another variable

Tags: shell

I need to write a shell script which does the following.
a=1;
b='abc'
my script should concatenate a and b and assign to c
thus c should carry 1abc

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate two variables simply by placing them adjacent to each other in the next assignment statement.

So in the statement of your problem:

```
$ a=1; b='abc'
```

then you can just do:

```
$ c="${a}${b}"
$ echo $c
1abc
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash
        set -o errtrace
        set -o errexit
        set -o pipefail

a= nzsql -host 10.8.5.105  -u twcsys1_ja_ops -pw dseg60k7yfgbyn -db COOKIE_UDP_TWCSYS1_DATA  -A -t -c 'select extract (month from (select conv_begin from rg))';
b= nzsql -host 10.8.5.105  -u twcsys1_ja_ops -pw dseg60k7yfgbyn -db COOKIE_UDP_TWCSYS1_DATA  -A -t -c 'select extract (month from (select conv_end from rg))';
echo $a;
i='impression_20150';
c="${i}${a}"
echo $c

Comment: but my desired result is impression_201504

Comment: that means: if i=impression_20150 and a=4 my result should give impression_201504

Comment: @Sonia that is not very legible, can you update the question instead so it's formatted better?

Comment: a=4
i='impression_20150';
c=${i}$a
and the expected result is impression_201504
how to concatenate this in shell?

Comment: @sonia, I cut & pasted your previous comment into a shell and it gives exactly the response you say you want, impression_201504, so I guess I don't understand what the additional question is.